# How can I show average by 2 month from Kibana TSVB?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk, kibana-7

I am ELK rookie 
I have a small question wanna ask here
How can I show average by  2 month from TSVB ?
Here is sample data like this :

```
  date                Execution Time                Job Name
20200102                 22                           Job 1
20200102                 33                           Job 2
20200202                 11                           Job 1
20200205                 45                           Job 3
20200210                100                           Job 5
20200311                 10                           Job 6
20200320                  1                           Job 9
20200417                 55                           Job 10
```

I want to show :

In X axis show every day
and Y axis show average by  2 month like this :

20200102 ---->  (22+33) /  2 (Different Job Count by every day  : Job1 and 2) 
Time range is from 20200102 to 20191102

2020202-----> (11 + 22 + 33) / 3  (Different Job Count by every day  : Job1 ,2 and  Job 1 from 0202 ) 
Time range is from 20200202 to 20191202

20200203 to 20200204 are no data , so is same as 20200202

20200205 -----> ( 45 + 11 + 22 + 33 ) / 4 
Time range is from 20200205 to 20191205

20200210 -----> ( 100 + 45 + 11 + 22 + 33  ) / 5
Time range is from 20200210 to 20191210

20200311 -----> (10 +  100 + 45 + 11 ) / 3
Time range is from 20200311 to 20200111
....

Please let me know if you have any comments :pray: :pray:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successful show on TSVB

I use Moving Average to fix time range problem, window size is 60 (2 month)

I use count and add Filter from option

finally use Bucket Script sol the problem :
params.moving_sum / params.moving_count